# Find all ranges outside of defined set of ranges

Tags: r, bioconductor, iranges

I am wondering what would be the best way to define all ranges which are not covered by given set of ranges. For example, if I have a set of genes with known coordinates:

```
dtGenes <- fread(
  "id,start,end
 1,1000,1300
 2,1200,1500
 3,1600,2600
 4,3000,4000
")
```

Let's say I know that total length of the chromosome (for simplicity, assume they are all on the same chromosome) is 10000. So, finally I expect to have the following list of intergenic regions:

```
"startR,endR
    0,1000
 1500,1600
 2600,3000
 4000,10000
"
```

can Bioconductor's `IRange` be useful here? or there is some other good way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Bioconductor package [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html), transform your original data to a `GRanges`

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr <- with(dtGenes, GRanges("chr1", IRanges(start, end, names=id),
                            seqlengths=c(chr1=10000)))
```

Then find the gaps between your genes

```
gaps <- gaps(gr)
```

`GRanges` knows about strand. You didn't specify a strand in the `GRanges` constructor, so strand was assigned `*`. There are therefore 'gaps' on the +, -, and * strands, and you're only interested in those on the * strand

```
> gaps[strand(gaps) == "*"]
GRanges with 4 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames        ranges strand
         <Rle>     <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr1 [   1,   999]      *
  [2]     chr1 [1501,  1599]      *
  [3]     chr1 [2601,  2999]      *
  [4]     chr1 [4001, 10000]      *
  ---
  seqlengths:
    chr1
   10000
```

Note the Bioconductor convention that chromosomes start at 1, and that the ranges are closed -- the `start` and `end` coordinates are included in the range. Use `shift` and `narrow` on `gr` to make your ranges consistent with Bioconductor conventions. GRanges operations are efficient on 10's of millions of ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` from `IRanges` package

> reduce first orders the ranges in x from left to right, then merges
>   the overlapping or adjacent ones.

```
library(IRanges)
dat <- read.csv(text="id,start,end
 1,1000,1300
 2,1200,1500
 3,1600,2600
 4,3000,4000
")

ir <- IRanges(dat$start,dat$end)
rir <- reduce(ir)
IRanges of length 3
    start  end width
[1]  1000 1500   501
[2]  1600 2600  1001
[3]  3000 4000  1001
```

Comment: thanks for pointing! `reduce` doesn't solve completely the task of finding the outside regions, but it does important first step of it; it will be definitely useful for me in some other cases, but for this given task I like very much the solution with `gaps` which does all job by single operation.

Comment: @VasilyA I don't use a lot iranges package. So of course MartinMorgan solution is the way to go here!